# Have variable changes on button click but initially set using localStorage in vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to setup a button that changes a data value in Vue but also have it set using localStorage initally. This way I can have it keep the previous state it was in before a page refresh. Below is the code I'm using and I'm able to get it to work but know that it would be preferable to use the computed section but haven't been able to get that to work properly.

Would anyone know what is going wrong?

My button is triggered using the testing method and the variable in question is isGrid.

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            option: 'default',
        }
    },
    components: {
        FileUploader,
    },
    mixins: [
        visibilitiesMixin,
        settingsMixin
    ],
    props: {
        vehicleId: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            default: null,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState([
            'isLoading',
            'images',
            'fallbackImageChecks',
            'selectedImages'
        ]),
        isGrid: {
            get() {
                return localStorage.getItem('isGrid');
            },
        },
        imagesVModel: {
            get() {
                return this.images;
            },
            set(images) {
                this.setImages(images);
            }
        },
        selectedImagesVModel: {
            get() {
                return this.selectedImages;
            },
            set(images) {
                this.setSelectedImages(images);
            }
        },
        removeBgEnabled() {
            return this.setting('nexus_integration_removebg_enabled') === 'enabled';
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loadImages(this.vehicleId);
    },
    methods: {
        testing() {
            if (this.isGrid === 'false' || this.isGrid === false) {
                localStorage.setItem('isGrid', true);
                this.isGrid = true;
                console.log(this.isGrid);
                console.log(localStorage.getItem('isGrid'));
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem('isGrid', false);
                this.isGrid = false;
                console.log('b');
                console.log(this.isGrid);
                console.log(localStorage.getItem('isGrid'));
            }
        },
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `vuex` with `vuex-persistedstate`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate

Comment: I am unable to use persistedstate unfortunately. Is there an alternative to get this to work with computed?